# MySqli: num_rows of grouped by hour()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with the rows: SearchTerm | userId | date | historyId

I need to get the amount of entries every hour in the last 24 hour period where the userId=userid.

So far I have as follows:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT historyId FROM webHistory WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY HOUR(date) AND userId=?");
```

I'm now a little stuck, how would I go about getting the num_rows for each hour group? I though about using count(*), but would this be the right method, if so how would I go about doing this?

Lastly, for mobile displays I would need to group by every two hour period, is this possible as I can only seem to find documentation on HOUR(), possibly DATEPART()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `count(*)`:

```
SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows
FROM webHistory
WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND userId=?
GROUP BY HOUR(date);
```

The condition on `userId` goes in the `where` clause.  It is good form to include the `hour(date)` in the `select`, so you know which hour a given count refers to.

EDIT:

To just get today's hours, hour can do:

```
SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows
FROM webHistory
WHERE date(date) = date(now()) AND userId=?
GROUP BY HOUR(date);
```

Comment: If run at 3:30pm, it will group 3:30-3:59 yesterday together with 3:00-3:29 today into the same group. May be by design, but more likely not.

Comment: Cheers for pointing that out Joachim, how would I go about making it so it only groups by hour of the current 24 hour period?

Comment: @JamieTurner That depends, exactly what data would you like for that group with a select at 3:30pm? Yesterday's 3pm-4pm since the hour today is not complete, or just the incomplete data for today's 3pm-3:30pm?

Comment: @ joachim: I basically need it to output the amount of rows in the database between two hour periods. So now to 24 hours ago, with the output being the hour to the amount: 15 => 4 So between 3 and 4pm 4 entries were found. Is there also a way to fall back to a default, so if no entries were found for hour 18 it would return 18=>0. I've tested Gordons answer and it seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To list data by two-hour periods:

```
SELECT FLOOR(HOUR(date)/2) AS period,historyId FROM webHistory, COUNT(*) as num_rows
 WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
 GROUP BY date, period
```

Comment: Thank you! sometimes I wish this site would allow multiple accepted answers!

Answer (score 2):

We can use SQL BETWEEN operator

```
SELECT HOUR(date) as hr, historyId, COUNT(*) as num_rows
FROM webHistory
WHERE date BETWEEN SUBDATE(date(now()),1) AND date(now()) 
AND userId=?
GROUP BY HOUR(date);
```